# Searching records conditions with hasMany model Cakephp3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, query-builder, cakephp-3.x

I have Orders model with hasMany OrderProducts model. below is my code.I have added search functionality using DataTable jquery plugin.Each OrderProducts contain ref_code.

I want to add search like fetch all Orders which has OrderProducts which contains ref_code GWG-SC-001(B) or whatever user enter in search field.

OrderTable.php

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\I18n\Time;

class OrdersTable extends Table
{
    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('orders');
        $this->displayField('id');
        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Users', [
            'propertyName' => 'Users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'className' => 'Users'
        ]);

        $this->belongsTo('OrderStatus', [
            'propertyName' => 'OrderStatus',
            'foreignKey' => 'order_status_id',
            'className' => 'OrderStatus'
        ]);

        $this->hasMany('OrderProducts', [
            'className' => 'OrderProducts',
            'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
            'className' => 'OrderProducts'
        ]);


        $this->hasMany('OrderPayments', [
            'propertyName' => 'OrderPayments',
            'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
            'className' => 'OrderPayments'
        ]);


    }
}


/**
 * [getOrdersList description]
 * @param  [type] $data [description]
 * @return [type]       [description]
 */
public function getOrdersList($data, $user_id = null)
{
    $orderelem = $data['columns'][$data['order'][0]['column']]['name'];
    $ordertype = $data['order'][0]['dir'];
    $offset = $data['start'];
    $limit = $data['length'];
    $conditions = array("Orders.payment_status <>" => 0);

    if (!empty($data['search']['value'])) {
        $like = '%' . trim($data['search']['value']) . '%';
        $like2 = $data['search']['value'];
        $orValues = array("Order Received");

        if (strpos($data['search']['value'], 'Status:') !== false) {
            $data['search']['value'] = str_replace('Status: ', '', $data['search']['value']);
            $orValues = explode("|", $data['search']['value']);
        }

        $conditions[] = array(
            "Orders.payment_status <>" => 0,
            'OR' => [
                'Users.first_name LIKE' => $like,
                'Users.last_name LIKE' => $like,
                'Users.title LIKE' => $like,
                'Orders.order_number LIKE' => $like2,
                //'Orders.quantity_count LIKE'    => $like2,
                //'Orders.all_total LIKE'         => $like2,
                'Orders.tracking_number LIKE' => $like,
                'OrderStatus.title' => $like,
                'OrderProducts.ref_code' => $like, // this is not working
            ]
        );
        if (!empty($orValues)) {
            $conditions[0]['OR']['OrderStatus.title IN'] = $orValues;
        }
    }

    $data2 = $this->find('all')
        ->select([
            'id', 'order_number', 'order_type', 'created', 'tracking_number',
            'delivery_methods_id', 'order_status_id', 'quantity_count',
            'all_total', 'payment_status', 'is_allow_final_payment'
        ])
        ->contain([
            'Users' => function ($u) {
                return $u->select(['title', 'first_name', 'last_name']);

            },
            'OrderStatus' => function ($os) {
                return $os->select(['status' => 'OrderStatus.title']);
            },
            'OrderProducts'
        ]);

    if ($user_id) {
        $data2 = $data2->where(['user_id' => $user_id])->andWhere($conditions);
    } else {
        $data2 = $data2->where($conditions);
    }

    $data2 = $data2->limit($limit)
        ->order([$orderelem => $ordertype])
        ->offset($offset)
        ->toArray();

    return $data2;
}
```

When I try this its giving below error:

> "message": "[PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column OrderProducts.ref_code in where clause

Please help me in this issue.

below query is generating:

```sql
SELECT
    Orders.id AS `Orders__id`,
    Orders.order_number AS `Orders__order_number`,
    Orders.order_type AS `Orders__order_type`,
    Orders.created AS `Orders__created`,
    Orders.tracking_number AS `Orders__tracking_number`,
    Orders.delivery_methods_id AS `Orders__delivery_methods_id`,
    Orders.order_status_id AS `Orders__order_status_id`,
    Orders.quantity_count AS `Orders__quantity_count`,
    Orders.all_total AS `Orders__all_total`,
    Orders.payment_status AS `Orders__payment_status`,
    Orders.is_allow_final_payment AS `Orders__is_allow_final_payment`,
    Users.title AS `Users__title`,
    Users.first_name AS `Users__first_name`,
    Users.last_name AS `Users__last_name`,
    OrderStatus.title AS `status` 
FROM
    orders Orders 
    LEFT JOIN
        users Users 
        ON Users.id = 
        (
            Orders.user_id
        )
    LEFT JOIN
        order_status OrderStatus 
        ON OrderStatus.id = 
        (
            Orders.order_status_id
        )
WHERE
    (
        Orders.payment_status \u003C\u003E :c0 
        AND 
        (
            Orders.payment_status \u003C\u003E :c1 
            AND 
            (
                Users.first_name like :c2 
                OR Users.last_name like :c3 
                OR Users.title like :c4 
                OR Orders.order_number like :c5 
                OR Orders.tracking_number like :c6 
                OR OrderStatus.title like :c7 
                OR OrderProducts.ref_code like :c8 
                OR OrderStatus.title in 
                (
                    :c9
                )
            )
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    Orders.created desc LIMIT 25 OFFSET 25
```

Comment: don't you think you should put `like`. `OrderStatus.title LIKE '         => $like,
                                    'OrderProducts.ref_code LIKE '         => $like,`

Comment: tried that still same error

Comment: check the log for query and then run that on phpmyadmin directly and paste that in your question too. One more thing do you have `ref_code` field in your `OrderProducts` table?

Comment: I have updated generated query above, i dont know why Left join not created with OrderProducts

Comment: yes ref_code is my OrderProducts table

Comment: Can you edit and put full query?

Comment: yes edited...please check

Comment: does your query work after removing `OrderProducts.ref_code` from condition?

Comment: yes irs working perfectly after I remove OrderProducts.ref_code

Comment: Can you add `'joinType' => 'INNER'` in `$this->hasMany('OrderProducts', [
            'className' => 'OrderProducts',
            'foreignKey' => 'order_id',
            'className' => 'OrderProducts',
'joinType' => 'INNER
        ]);`

Comment: its not working...

Comment: you have written`className` two times

Comment: Okay removed duplication.. still issue is there

Comment: so `OrderProducts` table is in join now?

Comment: @urfusion Contained `hasMany` associations will _always_ be retrieved in a separate query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use 'contain', it often actually generates separate queries for those contained models. As you can see, your "generated query" doesn't actually include `OrderProducts`, so in this case, it's generating a separate query for `OrderProducts`, then combining the results after.  Because of this, you cannot condition against a field that't not included in the query.

**TLDR:** Instead of containing OrderProducts, if you want to add conditions against another model, use a join instead.

Depending on your setup, you may be able to specify the `joinType` to `INNER` for the association.

If not, you can always just inner join as specified in the book here:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-innerjoinwith